# Visio VSTO add-in errors on Redo, even though original action works flawlessly

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, vsto, visio

In a Visio VSTO developed in VB.NET, for some user actions where a user adds a shape to a diagram, the action works fine (the user uses the context menu on a shape, which uses the [QUEUEMARKEREVENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/queuemarkerevent-function) function in the shapesheet to call the code in the add-in, which adds a shape to the shape from which the function is called).

This all works well without errors, however when performing an Undo/Redo upon Redo for some actions adding shapes as soon as I perform a Redo I see these errors during debugging in Visual Studio:

Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in ExtendedVisioAddin1.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll

The software performs well though and no errors or issues in the diagram and underlying data can be found. (also after a ton of Undo/Redos).

Is this a known issue for Visio developers that I shouldn't worry about as long as my software performs flawlessly for the end user (hopefully that is the answer from people who know Visio well), or should this be investigated in detail? (unfortunately information from Microsoft about how Visio Undo/Redo works in detail is hard to find).

Thank you for sharing your insights!

(to be sure, I have removed ALL other event handling code for isolating the issue, only the MarkerEvent is used so the user can execute the user action, so no events bouncing around and causing hard-to-isolate interactions)

Comment: What code do you have in the event handler?

Comment: Hi Eugene, you can find sample code that reproduces the issue here! Others have reproduced the issue since I posted the code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68861850/visio-vsto-add-in-queuemarker-event-from-shapesheet-user-action-adding-one-shap