# Visio VSTO Add-in QueueMarker event from shapesheet user action, adding one shape but getting two shapes upon Redo

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, vsto, visio

On Visio shapes on a Visio page, the only way to add Office Add-in functionality to the right-click mouse menu on Visio shapes is to use the [QUEUEMARKEREVENT shapesheet function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/queuemarkerevent-function).

Unfortunately, this way of letting the user use functionality on a Visio shape is causing issues with the Undo/Redo system.

I have made some sample code below that can be dropped in to a new Visio VSTO VB.NET Project in Visual Studio (I use 2019, Visio also version 2019)

Compile the VSTO add-in and when Visio starts up, choose a Basic Diagram as that opens up the stencil I use for the test.

Drop one shape on the page and edit the ShapeSheet to add an Action Section, as per this screenshot:

[image]

On this shape in the right-click menu you will find the "Test" menu item. Run this item and a new Square shape will be added to the page.

Now use Undo and then perform a Redo. If you move the new shape you will see there is an identical square shape below it. A Redo doesn't add one but actually two new shapes.

I think I am misunderstanding something about how the QueueMarker events work I am very much just an amateur developer, hopefully someone knows how to fix this robustly as reliable Undo/Redo behavior is very important for a good add-in application. Thank you for sharing your insights!

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Text
Imports Visio = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio

Partial Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub Application_MarkerEvent(app As Visio.Application, SequenceNum As Integer, ContextString As String) Handles Application.MarkerEvent

        Dim Stencil As Visio.Document

        Stencil = GetStencil()

        If Stencil Is Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("The Basic Shapes stencil is closed, please open it before running this action.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim Square As Visio.Shape

        Square = Application.ActivePage.Drop(Stencil.Masters.ItemU("Square"), 0, 0)

    End Sub

    Private Function GetStencil() As Visio.Document

        Dim DocCounter As Long

        For DocCounter = 1 To Application.Documents.Count

            If Application.Documents(DocCounter).Type = Visio.VisDocumentTypes.visTypeStencil Then

                If Application.Documents(DocCounter).Name = "BASIC_M.vssx" Or Application.Documents(DocCounter).Name = "BASIC_U.vssx" Then

                    'MessageBox.Show(Application.Documents(DocCounter).Name)

                    Return Application.Documents(DocCounter)

                    Exit Function

                End If

            End If

        Next DocCounter

        Return Nothing

    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the MarkerEvent is generated twice on Redo. Can you check for the ContextString to be == "Test" before processing it and see if it helps?

Comment: Tested this but on Redo the same ContextString is provided so the code executes also on Redo.

Comment: Does the Application_MarkerEvent with ContextString "Test" execute twice on Redo?

Comment: the Markerevent executes just once on Redo, and it executes with the "Test" contextstring as expected.